# Datanuclues L1Cache for readOnly

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I have been trying to analyze performance of JDO queries, (I am using the builtin dbcp with mysql).

I have noticed that while my query can be very fast, if a large number of records are returned, the query.execute() can be much slower (a 5ms db query can take 40ms in execute).

I have narrowed down the possible causes to the L1Cache:

> 2015-04-17 21:03:46.325 [work-3] DEBUG DataNucleus.Cache - Object with id ":758" not found in Level 1 cache [cache size = 153]
>
> 2015-04-17 21:03:46.325 [work-3] DEBUG DataNucleus.Cache - Object "@442b0b9e" (id=":758") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[NYNNNNN]")
>
> 2015-04-17 21:03:46.325 [work-3] DEBUG DataNucleus.Cache - Object with id ":759" not found in Level 1 cache [cache size = 154]
>
> 2015-04-17 21:03:46.325 [work-3] DEBUG DataNucleus.Cache - Object "@3f978ede" (id=":759") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[NYNNNNN]")
>
> 2015-04-17 21:03:46.326 [work-3] DEBUG DataNucleus.Cache - Object with id ":760" not found in Level 1 cache [cache size = 155]
>
> 2015-04-17 21:03:46.326 [work-3] DEBUG DataNucleus.Cache - Object "@2e0f44f5" (id=":760") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[NYNNNNN]")
>
> 2015-04-17 21:03:46.326 [work-3] DEBUG DataNucleus.Cache - Object with id ":761" not found in Level 1 cache [cache size = 156]
>
> 2015-04-17 21:03:46.326 [work-3] DEBUG DataNucleus.Cache - Object "@7db2fe20" (id=":761") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[NYNNNNN]")

This is showing that each record is first checked (to see if it is alreayd in the cache, and then inserted into the cache). With 100 or 1000's of records the performance of this seems to be fairly demanding.

In addition when the PersistenceManager is closed (i am using a try with resources), this cache is then destroyed. (
So for a simple select * from Table:

- we obtain the record
- we convert to Class
- we check if its already in the L1 cahce (for a single read it won't be)
- we insert into cache
- the query is complete
- the PersistenceManager is closed
- the cache is emptied of records (one at time).

Here is some sample code:

```
        try (final PersistenceManagerProvider pmp = getReadPmp()) {
            Query q = pmp.get().newQuery(clazz, ":param1.contains(" + field + ")");
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") List<T> result = (List<T>) q.execute(values);
            return result;
        }
```

In this example, the try is a try with resources. close will look something like this:

```
    @Override
    public void close() {
        if (tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
            final String stackTrace = new Throwable().getStackTrace()[1].toString(); // element 0 is this method
            LOGGER.error("ROLLING BACK UNCOMMITTED TRANSACTION FROM " + stackTrace);
            tx.rollback(); // never throws if isActive() is true
        }

        persistenceManager.close();
}
```

It seems like for queries such as this, where I am simply reading in the select, The cache is not providing me anything so it should not suck up my performance. (By the way i have tried disabling l1 cache and that apparently wasn't a good idea).

Here is a full set of logs from the query: 
https://gist.github.com/djerraballi/fafa48a0fa0fea18b31a
Theses are debug logs (which probably slows down the query quite significantly, but still support the theory that calls to remove the objects from the cache as well as insert are both sequential and time consuming).

Comment: You don't say where the time is taken. Query generic compile? Query datastore compile? execution? extract results from ResultSet? Transaction commit (and object lifecycle changes)? An L1 cache is a Map, nothing more, and is needed to only hand out a single object with a particular object id, as per the JDO (and JPA) spec. I see no cache is emptied of records "one at time" ... cache.clear is called (on a Map)

Comment: The time is being spent in JDOQL performExecute, but i will post full logs gathered, so we can see both the cache being cleared and the cache being constructed for each record. I edited to attach a gist with the full logs, (I am guessing since the destruction/adding are being logged sequentially (i can see time between the logs), they are being called sequentially. That might be a bad assumption.

Comment: Another thing you can see here is that the actualy query and compile times are quick. Most of the time in the logs is spent with the L1 cache.

Comment: I see log messages that an object is removed from the L1 cache, *but that doesn't mean that all time is in the L1 cache til the next message*; as said, removing an object from a Map is trivial. Why not look at their code?